# Making from a closed curve in the 3-dimensional euclidian space, a non-closed curve in a plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

Find explicitly a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that if I create a new curve, from the previous one, with the same curvature but with torsion zero, this one is not closed.

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking. From your titel, and not the question body, we guess you are somehow projecting the curve onto a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is that it? And is that via linear projection?

Comment: The process is as follows. Starting with a closed curve in the space, I move a point in a plane, such that the point describes the same curvature of the closed curve in the 3-space. So I am not projecting.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not too clear, I am not an english native speaker. :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you just projecting your curve onto the plane? If so its image must also be closed.

The continuous image of a closed curve is also closed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a projection. I have to create a plane curve, which shares the curvature with the 3-dimensional curve.

Comment: A detailed description of the question is above. That is the best attempt I can make.